# add Spinner to action bar in Fragment in Android

Tags: android-spinner

Could any one tell me, how to **add Spinner to action bar** in Fragment ?

Answer (score 3):

I solved that issue by using below steps

**Step - 1**

Create xml file in  Layout folder(Consider Layout name is **spinnerwound.xml**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#F79D27"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spin"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Step - 2**

In Fragment Write like this

```
    ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View vi = inflator.inflate(R.layout.spinnerwound, null);

    Spinner s = (Spinner) vi.findViewById(R.id.spin);

    spinnerlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    spinnerlist.add(Item1);
    spinnerlist.add(Item2);

    spinneradapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, spinnerlist);

    s.setAdapter(spinneradapter);

    ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(vi);

    spinneradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {

//Do what ever you want

}
```

Comment: It is exactly the same. I am using toolbar